# Использование оператора "Или" с String

Tags: c#

При создании калькулятора на C# возникла проблема. С использованием || цикл идёт бесконечно
Код:

```
String o;
o = (Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What are you want to do? +, -, /, *?");
    o = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (o != "+" || o != "-" || o != "*" || o != "/");
```

Comment: Замените скриншот Вашим кодом

Comment: А попробуйте `&&` вместо `||`.

Comment: Убрал свой минус за оформление вопроса (было: код картинкой)

Comment: Убрал лишний код, не имеющий отношения к вопросу

Comment: Ну так у вас условие всегда выполняется, строка никогда не будет равна сразу четырем разным строкам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ...
}
while (o != "+" && o != "-" && o != "/" && o != "*");
```

Я исправил логические операторы в условии `while` на правильные, потому что переменная не может одновременно равняться четырем разным значениям.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

```
while (o != "+" || o != "-" || o != "*" || o != "/");
```

выполнять цикл пока `o` не равно `+` или `o` не равно `-`...

Или обратно. Выйти из цикла когда `o` будет равно `+` и `o` будет равно `-`...

`o` не может быть одновременно быть равно и `+` и `-`, следовательно, из цикла мы никогда не выйдем.

Теперь перепишем условие

```
while (o == "+" || o == "-" || o == "*" || o == "/");
```

выполнять цикл пока `o` равно `+` или `o` равно `-`...

Или обратно. Выйти из цикла когда `o` не будет равно `+` и `o` не будет равно `-`...

Получим штатный выход когда `o` будет любой строкой, отличной от `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`